# Geolocation - enter latitude and longitude directly

Tags: 2013, geolocation

The GeoLocation feature allows users to enter longitude and latitude directly through a window when setting up or editing an item.

I would like to be able to either

a) calculate the geolocation from other columns (Address, ZIP, City, Country)
b) be able to enter latitude and longitude manually in the list (I have a list of x clients that I wish to see on a map). I was able to import the list, I even have lat and long for every single one of them but the geolocation column cannot be manipulated at this point.

What are my options? What can I do?

Comment: Part a) is called geocoding and you would need a service that does that. I would presume there is some kind of Bing service for that. For part B) Maybe use REST api? I've poked at it and a single entry is some kind of lookup which includes Altitude, Latitude, Longitude, and Measure. And/or client side rendering?